# How to calculate correlation of two variables in a huge data set in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I've got a huge data set with six columns (call them A, B, C, D, E, F), about 450,000 rows. I simply tried to find the correlation between columns `A` and `B`:

```
cor(A, B)
```

and I got

> [1] NA

as a result. What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 13):

Try `cor(A,B, use = "pairwise.complete.obs")`.  That will ignore the NAs in your observations.

To be statistically rigorous, you should also look at the # of missing entries in your data and look at whether the missing at random assumption holds.

Edit 1: Take a look at `?cor` to see other options for the `use` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using the rcorr function in the Hmisc package.

It is very fast, and only includes pairwise complete observations. The returned object contains a matrix

1. of correlation scores
2. with the number of observation used for each correlation value
3. of a p-value for each correlation

Some example code is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445639/dealing-with-missing-values-for-correlations-calculation-in-r/7460534#7460534):